# gitlab ci couldn't use variables in script

Tags: node.js, gitlab, mocha.js, gitlab-ci

I would like to run test on gitlab. I am using a simple yml file, but i want to send path to test through the variables. But when i run this job i get error: $ npm run mocha "$TEST_VAR" --timeout=1200000 --reporter mocha-allure-reporter
npm ERR! Missing script: "mocha"

```
image: node:latest
    
    cache:
      paths:
        - node_modules/
    
    stages:
      - setup
      - test
    
    setup:node_modules:
      stage: setup
      script:
        - npm install
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - node_modules/
          - package-lock.json
    
    test:
        stage: test
     variables:
          TEST_VAR: "test/test.js"
        script:
            - echo "$TEST_VAR"
            - npm run mocha "$TEST_VAR" --timeout=1200000 --reporter mocha-allure-reporter
        dependencies:
            - setup:node_modules
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message `npm ERR! Missing script: "mocha"` is actually saying that npm can't find a script called "mocha" in the package.json's `scripts` block.

If you wish to run mocha directly from .gitlab-ci.yml using variables instead of writing the script in the package.json's scripts block, then this may be more what you're looking for:

```
test:
  stage: test
  variables:
    TEST_VAR: "test/test.js"
  script:
    - echo "$TEST_VAR"
    - npm i mocha -g
    - npm i mocha-allure-reporter -g
    - mocha "$TEST_VAR" --timeout=1200000 --reporter mocha-allure-reporter --exit
  dependencies:
    - setup:node_modules
```